# Copying data want to keep to a new table and then rename

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, database-performance

I have a Windows 2008 Ent. Server running SQL 2008 Ent.  There's a SQL DB that is approximately 100Gb in size.  One of the tables in this database accounts for 85Gb.  After doing some analysis this one table has got to this size from one event being logged which has no value so it's been agreed that we can purge all instances of this event from this table.  The table should be only around 1Gb in size once all occurrences of this event have been removed.

Someone suggested to me that a more efficient approach rather than going through trying to delete rows which include this event id to perhaps create the table again with no data.  Copy the data that we want to keep to the new table (ommitting any row with event id).  Rename the original table to something and then rename the new table to original table name.

The approach makes sense and I can see that perhaps this will be faster than deleting 100 rows at a time out of the original table.  Can I please have some advice on how to go about this?

Comment: From where did the requirement to delete only 100 rows at a time come?

Comment: May be this isn't necessary but I thought it was better to do batches of 100.  There are over 200,000,000 rows of this event to delete. Anyway don't think I'm going with this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query to copy everything to the new table goes like this:

```
SELECT * INTO dbo.NewTable FROM dbo.OldTable WHERE [event id] <> 6030
```

Then:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.OldTable
  RENAME TO dbo.OldTable_History;
```

And:

```
 ALTER TABLE dbo.NewTable 
  RENAME TO dbo.OldTable;
```

If you want to create the table manually do it then and after that run this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.NewTable
SELECT * FROM dbo.OldTable WHERE [event id] <> 6030
```

Comment: @DanBracuk SQL 2008 yes it does. Why not?

Comment: The why not part is that there is no create table query.  Also, what makes you so sure the OP is using sql server?

Comment: @DanBracuk First line of his post.

Comment: Oops, I only noticed the tags.

Comment: Thanks very much.  If I don't want to copy everything from the old table is the most efficient way to use <> event id where the event id is what I don't want to copy across?  There are 200,000,000 rows of this event id.

Comment: @user2841861 EventId is a column of your first table?

Comment: yep, so the event id I don't want to copy to the new table is 6030

Comment: Perfect thanks.  I notice the select statement insists on creating the new table.  If I want to create the new table manually beforehand i.e with all the corect constraints how can I do this?

Comment: Ok. Check answer again. :P

Comment: absolutely perfect.  Thanks for the top notch advice.

Comment: just got this error.Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
An explicit value for the identity column in table 'dbo.R_TransactionEvent_New' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Comment: INSERT INTO dbo.NewTable
SELECT * FROM dbo.OldTable WHERE [event id] <> 6030

Comment: Put the all the columns then and not the asterisks. Both in insert and Select. ex. insert into dbo.NewTable(Id,eventId) select Id,eventId FROM dbo.OldTable WHERE [eventid] <> 6030